# Redis Store with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, socket.io

What is the benefit of using Redis as socket.io memory store, does it need additional resources. I'm using MongoDB as the database, can i use MongoDB as memory store for Socket.io, or do i replace MongoDB with Redis as database? What would be more efficient for building a real-time web app and providing maximum concurrent connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i use MongoDB as memory store for Socket.io

**[Yes, you can try mong.socket.io](https://github.com/tmfkmoney/mong.socket.io)**

> do i replace MongoDB with Redis as database?

Redis and MongoDB are different kind of databases, while mongodb is document oriented redis is key/value oriented (we can even say that redis is a data-structure server).

> What would be more efficient for building a real-time web app and providing maximum concurrent connections?

Redis will be definitely faster than mongo on that matter, it supports pub/sub out of the box (while mong.socket.io uses a collection to simulate pub/sub) but you must know that all your data stored in redis must live in memory (here the only data that will be stored in redis will be additionnal socket.io informations).